# PHP: DatePeriod with last day of month

Tags: php, datetime

I'd like to work with PHP DateInterval to iterate through months:

```
$from = new DateTime();
$from->setDate(2014, 1, 31);

$period = new DatePeriod($from, new DateInterval('P1M'), 12);
```

I'd expect it to returns 31 January, 28 February (as the DateInterval is 1 month), but it actually returns 31 January, 3 March, 3 of April... hence skipping February.

Is there any way to do this simply?

Thanks!

EDIT : as a refernece, here is a solution that seems to cover most use cases:

```
$date = new DateTime('2014-01-31');
$start = $date->format('n');

for ($i = 0; $i < 28; $i++) {
  $current = clone $date;
  $current->modify('+'.$i.' month');

  if ($current->format('n') > ($start % 12) && $start !== 12) {
    $current->modify('last day of last month');
  }

  $start++;

  echo $current->format('Y-m-d').PHP_EOL;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`DateTime::modify()`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.modify.php):

```
$date = new DateTime('last day of january');
echo $date->format('Y-m-d').PHP_EOL;

for ($i = 1; $i < 12; $i++) {
  $date->modify('last day of next month');
  echo $date->format('Y-m-d').PHP_EOL;
}
```

**EDIT:** I think I didn't understand your question clearly. Here is a new version:

```
$date = new DateTime('2014-01-31');

for ($i = 0; $i < 12; $i++) {
  $current = clone $date;
  $current->modify('+'.$i.' month');

  if ($current->format('n') > $i + 1) {
    $current->modify('last day of last month');
  }

  echo $current->format('Y-m-d').PHP_EOL;
}
```

Comment: This only works if you need the last day of the month. Actually I want to iterate and make it works in all cases (so it should also work by iterating each month starting from 2 of January, for instance).

Comment: I see. Updated my answer with a new code. Can you please test it and let me know if this is what you wanted?

Comment: Yes, I tried various edge cases with February and it seems to work perfectly well! (although I still find the behavior of DatePeriod is not logical...). Thanks a lot

Comment: Actually, there are some cases where it fails: if you change 12 to 24 months, it starts to fail starting in 2015 ;). I'll try to see how I can fix that.

Comment: Pretty easy actually, just need to do a modulo 12: if ($current->format('n') > ($i % 12) + 1. But now it fails in other cases (if you don't start in January, for instance).

Comment: I thought you needed this for only one year. Yes, modulo should do the trick. Please also note that this code works only if you iterate from January. I will need to update it if the starting month can be anything.

Comment: I've updated my initial question that a solution that seems to work. Maybe it could be optimized a bit, but seems to handle all cases.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is cause by the variance between the last day in each of the months within the range. ie. February ending on `28` instead of `31` and the addition of 1 month from the last day `2014-01-31 + 1 month = 2014-03-03` https://3v4l.org/Y42QJ

To resolve the issue with `DatePeriod` and simplify it a bit, adjust the initial date by resetting the specified date to the first day of the specified month, by using `first day of this month`.

Then during iteration, you can modify the date period date by using `last day of this month` to retrieve the bounds of the currently iterated month.

### Example: https://3v4l.org/889mB

```
$from = new DateTime('2014-01-31');
$from->modify('first day of this month'); //2014-01-01

$period = new DatePeriod($from, new DateInterval('P1M'), 12);
foreach ($period as $date) {
    echo $date->modify('last day of this month')->format('Y-m-d');
}
```

**Result:**

```
2014-01-31
2014-02-28
2014-03-31
2014-04-30
2014-05-31
2014-06-30
2014-07-31
2014-08-31
2014-09-30
2014-10-31
2014-11-30
2014-12-31
2015-01-31
```

---

Then to expand on this approach, in order to retrieve the desired day from the specified date, such as the `29th`. You can extract the specified day and adjust the currently iterated month as needed when the day is out of bounds for that month.

### Example: https://3v4l.org/SlEJc

```
$from = new DateTime('2014-01-29');
$day = $from->format('j');
$from->modify('first day of this month'); //2014-01-01

$period = new DatePeriod($from, new DateInterval('P1M'), 12);
foreach ($period as $date) {
    $lastDay = clone $date;
    $lastDay->modify('last day of this month');
    $date->setDate($date->format('Y'), $date->format('n'), $day);
    if ($date > $lastDay) {
       $date = $lastDay;
    }
    echo $date->format('Y-m-d');
}
```

Result:

```
2014-01-29
2014-02-28 #notice the last day of february is used
2014-03-29
2014-04-29
2014-05-29
2014-06-29
2014-07-29
2014-08-29
2014-09-29
2014-10-29
2014-11-29
2014-12-29
2015-01-29
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try like this:

```
$date = new DateTime();
$lastDayOfMonth = $date->modify(
  sprintf('+%d days', $date->format('t') - $date->format('j'))
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do it probably like this

```
$max = array (
31,28,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31
); //days in month

$month = 1;
$year = 2014;
$day = 31;

$iterate = 12;
$dates = array();
for ($i = 0;$i < $iterate;$i++) {
    $tmp_month = ($month + $i) % 12;
    $tmp_year = $year + floor($month+$i)/12;
    $tmp_day = min($day, $max[$tmp_month]);
    $tmp = new DateTime();
    $tmp->setDate($tmp_year, $tmp_month + 1, $tmp_day);
    $dates[] = $tmp;
}

var_dump($dates);
```

This keeps to the same day each month if possible

Comment: This seems like the "less bad" solution. Although I'm afraid it will need some tweaks (like taking into account years where there are 29 days in February).